# Returning list basic c sharp

Tags: c#, rest

I am new to programming and been tasked to grab data from an API.

The issue I have is basic C# returning the contents of brakeparts. I'm passing the part id and obtaining a list of brake parts correctly. I need to assign the partid to the list, which seems to work when adding a breakpoint, however how do I return this list? Return brake parts doesn't work. They could be potentially many parts it returns whilst looping I need it to append to the Parts list. I know its probably something quite simple but I can't get my head around returning back the whole list.  I've tried brakeparts.AddRange(brakeparts);  This doesn't work too.

```
private static List<Parts> getBrakeparts(List<int> partids)
{
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://example.example.net/api");
    foreach (var partid in partids)
    {
        var returnreq = new RestRequest($"/brakeparts/{partid}/ ", Method.GET);
 
        var res = restClient.Execute(returnreq);
 
        Parts brakeparts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parts>(res.Content);
 
        brakeparts.PartID = partid;             
 
    }
    
    return brakeparts;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, looks like you got an answer already, but a coding tip: Try to be descriptive on your variable names. Instead `var restClient`  you could `var breaksApi`. That will help your future you or others understanding your code. Note: I am not saying your coding is poor, only giving advice

Comment: Thanks, I will make a note of that, I'm very much learning so any of these tips are welcomed.  Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you're simply trying to return a list of parts which you want to fill with the `Parts breakparts` that you deserialized from the Json response.
Simply create a `List<Parts>` instance and add the breakparts to it in the loop.
It could look like the following.

```cs
private static List<Parts> getBrakeparts(List<int> partids)
{
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://example.example.net/api");

    List<Parts> parts = new List<Parts>();
    foreach (var partid in partids)
    {
        var returnreq = new RestRequest($"/brakeparts/{partid}/ ", Method.GET);

        var res = restClient.Execute(returnreq);

        Parts brakeparts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parts>(res.Content);
        brakeparts.PartID = partid;

        parts.Add(brakeparts);
    }

    return parts;
}
```

Comment: also you should us IList instead of List for loose coupling

Comment: @kraego Agreed, but I decided against it, as it could potentially cause more harm than good for this basic question.

Comment: @kraego - Can you tell me a scenario where that helps with `IList<T>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity: In this specific case List vs. IList it makes no difference. But it's good practice to programm to Interfaces rather than concrete Implementations (to be more flexible ... loose coupling), just mentioned it cause esjay said he is a noob

Comment: Thanks so much that worked perfectly.  I've spent a week trying to find a solution watching many tutorials and reading articles.

Comment: @kraego - Yes, I agree in general. I just wondered about `IList<T>` in your experience?